# JSTL XML Transforms not working with nested XSL includes

Tags: xml, xslt, jstl

I have a bit of JSP that does this:

```
<c:import url="/xsl/Transformer.xsl" var="xslt" />
<x:transform doc="${actionBean.dom}" xslt="${xslt}" xsltSystemId="/xsl/">
```

This transforms the XML exactly as expected so long as Transformer.xsl contains no `<xsl:include>` tags or so long as any documents it does include do not include anything.

However, if I use an XSL which includes a document which in turn includes another document, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  'Invalid URI 'NestedInclude.xsl
Could not resolve entity reference: "NestedInclude.xsl"'.'
```

Note that the JSP is contained in the directory below the xsl documents. If all my XSLs and JSPs are in the same directory (and I remove the xsltSystemId attribute) then everything would work fine, but I don't really want to do this.

Can anyone see anything I'm doing wrong, as it's a bit of a killer at the moment and the JSTL documentation is next to useless.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide a value for the `xsltSystemId` attribute that starts with "/", I believe JSTL will use an `EntityResolver` that attempts to locate: `PageContext.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(xsltSystemId)`. So, you might try either `xsltSystemId="/xsl/Transformer.xsl"`, or just leave out the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I could solve it by giving absolute path. something like this:

```
<c:import url="/WEB-INF/some-folders/xsl/Transformer.xsl"/>
```